# How to programmatically build RFT project?

Tags: build, rft

I use SVN manage my RFT test scripts. I need to repeatedly check out the code to a clean RFT workspace and build the whole project, for some special requirement. I want to automate this process, which means I need to build the project without manually start RFT. Is there any command or API I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use APT to programmatically build a RFT project.

"C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\eclipsec.exe" -nosplash -application org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild -data MYWORKSPACE

There is also an ANT task for this as well, but haven't got it working. Do a google search for APT or headless eclipse build.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really silly way of doing it but it might work.  Open two instances of RFT.  You can do this by using a different workspace for each one.  Create a script in one that automates the building of your project in the other.  There you have it, an automated script to build the whole project.